# Seeing huge latency using FFMPEG to send RTMPS

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, latency, rtmp

Seeing huge latency when running FFMPEG to (re)stream camera RTSP stream into RTMPS. Running the same command using RTMP works fine without any latency.

Below are the commands used in our testing. Notice how the speed drops significantly when using RTMPS:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin>ffmpeg -hide_banner -rtsp_flags prefer_tcp -i "rtsp://user:password@192.168.77.136/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1" -codec copy -fflags nobuffer -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -muxpreload 3.5 -f flv "rtmp://xxxxxxxxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3388/WebRTCAppEE/teststream1"
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:password@192.168.77.136/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m, progressive), 704x480 [SAR 40:33 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 100 tbr, 90k tbn
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3388/WebRTCAppEE/teststream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
    encoder         : Lavf60.5.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m, progressive), 704x480 [SAR 40:33 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 100 tbr, 1k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[flv @ 000002091d30d540] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[flv @ 000002091d30d540] Failed to update header with correct duration.4.9kbits/s speed=1.04x
[flv @ 000002091d30d540] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[out#0/flv @ 000002091d2f76c0] video:2289kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.906316%
frame= 1045 fps= 31 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2309kB time=00:00:34.76 bitrate= 544.2kbits/s **speed=1.04x**
```

With RTMPS:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin>ffmpeg -hide_banner -rtsp_flags prefer_tcp -i "rtsp://user:password@192.168.77.136/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1" -codec copy -fflags nobuffer -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -muxpreload 3.5 -f flv "rtmps://xxxxxxxxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3389/WebRTCAppEE/teststream1"
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:password@192.168.77.136/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m, progressive), 704x480 [SAR 40:33 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 100 tbr, 90k tbn
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmps://xxxxxxxxxxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3389/WebRTCAppEE/teststream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
    encoder         : Lavf60.5.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m, progressive), 704x480 [SAR 40:33 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 100 tbr, 1k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[flv @ 000001a39c1ad480] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[rtsp @ 000001a39a61a000] CSeq 7 expected, 6 received.26.54 bitrate= 276.6kbits/s **speed=0.386x**
[flv @ 000001a39c1ad480] Failed to update header with correct duration.6.9kbits/s **speed=0.601x**
[flv @ 000001a39c1ad480] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[out#0/flv @ 000001a39c1572c0] video:1176kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.737466%
frame=  427 fps=5.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1184kB time=00:00:48.82 bitrate= 198.7kbits/s **speed=0.576x**
```